# is multi client copy objects in S3 allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

We can copy objects to different buckets in the same namespace using.

```
        CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
            .copySourceIfMatch(encodedUrl)
            .destinationBucket(toBucket)
            .destinationKey(objectKey)
            .build();
        CopyObjectResponse copyRes = s3.copyObject(copyReq);
```

But if I need to transfer file to another namespace (so different connection details) - how it can be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "different connection details"? Are you saying that you want to use a different set of credentials, presumably to copy an object to an Amazon S3 bucket owned by a different AWS Account? Please Edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: right, different set of credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `copyObject()`, you must use a single set of credentials that has **Read** permission on the source bucket and **Write** permission on the destination bucket.

Assuming that you want to copy the object between **buckets owned by different AWS Accounts**, then your options are:

#### Option 1: Push

This option uses credentials from the AWS Account that owns the 'source' bucket. You will need:

- Permission on the IAM User/IAM Role to `GetObject` from the source bucket
- A **Bucket Policy on the destination bucket** that permits `PutObject` from the IAM User/IAM Role being used
- I recommend you also set `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` to give the destination bucket ownership of the object

#### Option 2: Pull

This option uses credentials from the AWS Account that owns the 'destination' bucket. You will need:

- A **Bucket Policy on the source bucket** that permits `GetObject` from the IAM User/IAM Role being used
- Permission on the IAM User/IAM Role to `PutObject` to the destination bucket

#### Your situation

You mention "different connection details", so I assume that these are credentials that have been given to you by the owner of the 'other' account. As per the options above:

- If your account is the source account, add a Bucket Policy that permits `GetObject` using those credentials
- If your account is the destination account, add a Bucket Policy that permits `PutObject` using those credentials and use `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control`